# What was removed between the Japanese and English releases of "Odin: Photon Space Sailer Starlight"?

Tags: odin-starlight-mutiny

The anime film [**Odin: Photon Space Sailer Starlight**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odin%3a_Photon_Sailer_Starlight) was released in Japan with a running time of 139 minutes, but Central Park Media's U.S. release of the movie is only 93 minutes long. This results in a whopping *45 minutes* of footage edited out. I realize there was no real ending to the movie since it was originally planned to be a trilogy, and that the film itself is kind of slow to begin with. But what did the U.S. release edit out? Was there a specific chunk(s) of the story that was removed? Or did they somehow remove all of the panning, random action, and borderline long still shots throughout the movie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Editing_of_anime_in_American_distribution#Length):

> Many earlier anime theatrical films had slow deliberate pacing resulting in running times that were over two hours. Odin: Photon Sailer Starlight, whose original runtime was two hours 15 minutes had a pre-credits sequence, numerous surrealistic special effects scenes, lengthy dialogue scenes, silent moments, as well as a musical ending (special appearance by [Loudness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loudness_%28band%29), the band who performed some of the music numbers), all of which were cut resulting in a 90 minute English dub.

So the answer appears to be "All of the above".

(I've not seen the movie yet.)

Comment: No idea how I missed that on wikipedia, I skimmed that page before asking. Strange about the Loudness music video bit, since that happened during the ending credits. Did they just take out the credits and made them much shorter?

Comment: @JonLin The wiki mentions *pre*-credits and _musical_ ending rather than simply _credits_. They might be three different things.

Comment: Well, that's why I'm a bit confused, there's definitely a long sequence in the beginning of the movie with rock music in the background, but the "musical ending" is simply [during the ending credits](http://i.stack.imgur.com/iDC4V.png), the pre-credit sequence is this really long, set of shots with the ship, doing nothing, so I can see them getting rid of that. But the musical ending seems to be the same as the credits. It ends at the end of the credits.